Colors on Damage Counter in Mortal Kombat 1 (2023)
When fighting in MK1, a counter appears telling how much damage the character is causing to the opponent. Sometimes the counter color is red, other times it is orange with some shades of red and yellow. What does the colors mean? Sometimes an entire combo is red, sometimes, orange. Most one-hit moves are orange. Any ideas?

From what i could find online
In Mortal Kombat 1, the damage counter colors are used to provide visual feedback on the type of damage being inflicted. However, these cues are often implicit, requiring the player to understand and adapt based on expierence and observation rather than being explicitly stated on screen.
ORANGE

Orange is the standard color used for normal damage. This includes damage from regular attacks, combos, and most one-hit moves. It represents the typical level of damage a move inflicts.

YELLOW

Yellow is used for a move that does minimal damage or was timed incorrectly.

RED

Red is used for high-impact damage. This often signifies moves that are more powerful or significant, such as those with special effects or cinematic impacts.

There are scenarios where the same attack can show different colors based on the context of the hit.
Normal hit vs critical hit
A regular attack will display an orange damage counter unless the attack is enhanced or a critical hit (e.g. due to a special condition or enhanced version of the move)
Combo extenders
Moves that are part of a combo show a different color if they are the final hit in a sequence or if they trigger a special effect.
The source states the invasion gamemode in which elemental strengths would show red numbers when connected and weaknesses orange (or possibly yellow).

I did not see anything on the link you provided. Can you provide another one? Also, this answer looks a lot like the one ChatGPT provided me, which in turn was referring to another game.
